# How to make a custom UITextField Placeholder in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, textfield, placeholder

I'm building an app who has to obtain the address and some information of the user. I have one UIViewController with three UITextFields and I want to display the placeholders of each TextField like this picture.

**Mockup Design of the UIViewController**

[image: Click Here to see the Picture]

How can I do that?

Comment: The docs are here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfield

Answer (score 1):

`UITextField` has built-in placeholder functionality. Just set the `placeholder` property of your text field:

```
textField.placeholder = "Casa 9 manzana E"
```

You can style the text field as needed. Take a look at the `UITextField` documentation for more details: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfield

Answer (score 0):

For multi-line, styled placeholders consider using `attributedPlaceholder`.
`NSAttributedString` allows to modify/style parts of the string differently.

Answer (score 0):

You need To try This

Txtpwd.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Your Text",attributes: [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName=UIColor.darkGray])

Where TXTPwd in Outlet of Yore TextField